# Unable to access AWS endpoints

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I am using following CURL command to access AWS api's via deltacloud:

**curl --user "accesskey:secretaccesskey" -H "X-Deltacloud-Driver:ec2" -H "X-Deltacloud-Provider:us-east-1" "http://IPofdeltacloud.com:3001/api/images?format=xml"**

But I am getting following error again and again:

```
Aws::AwsError:RequestExpired: Request has expired. Timestamp date is 2013-11-21T12:57:45.000Z
REQUEST=ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443/?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIQUAMKYUKBM2RDMA&Action=DescribeImages&Filter.1.Name=image-type&Filter.1.Value.1=machine&Owner.1=amazon&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2013-11-21T12%3A57%3A45.000Z&Version=2010-08-31&Signature=OfCOFQKH0lBMbHA4pofIBekmRfXEysAI%2F5c8YIjugUM%3D 
REQUEST ID=62efe75b-dbad-4a3c-bb0f-d49eaced2d78 
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-2.5.6/lib/awsbase/awsbase.rb:579:in `request_info_impl'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-2.5.6/lib/ec2/ec2.rb:179:in `request_info'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-2.5.6/lib/awsbase/awsbase.rb:593:in `request_cache_or_info'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-2.5.6/lib/ec2/ec2.rb:207:in `ec2_describe_images'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-2.5.6/lib/ec2/ec2.rb:252:in `describe_images_by_owner'
/root/testgit/deltacloud/server/lib/deltacloud/drivers/ec2/ec2_driver.rb:155:in `block in images'
/root/testgit/deltacloud/server/lib/deltacloud/drivers/exceptions.rb:173:in `call'
/root/testgit/deltacloud/server/lib/deltacloud/drivers/exceptions.rb:173:in `safely'
/root/testgit/deltacloud/server/lib/deltacloud/drivers/ec2/ec2_driver.rb:154:in `images'
/root/testgit/deltacloud/server/lib/deltacloud/helpers/deltacloud_helper.rb:58:in `block in filter_all'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:280:in `measure'
```

Can anyone suggest me what wrong is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You have a time skew on your server, and AWS checks the timestamp of the request in order to prevent replay attacks.

You have to set the correct time on your server. If you're running ubuntu, you can use the following bash command:

```
ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Used your command: [root@localhost bin]# ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
21 Nov 13:38:56 ntpdate[17053]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting, But still the same error

Comment: where are you running the command? On the deltacloud server, or on your local machine? in either case, you can try to: sudo service ntp stop

Comment: On the deltacloud server

Comment: Current time on my system is: Thu Nov 21 14:02:16 UTC 2013 and in the error I am getting timestamp as: 2013-11-21T14:02:48.000Z

Comment: probably there is a running ntpd ("the NTP socket is in use, exiting"),

just add the "-u" switch: ntpdate -u pool.ntp.org